# Assigning Reference Numbers or Unique Strings of Text in a Variable (SQL)

Tags: sql, reference, unique

I've become a bit stuck on a report I'm required to build, but would be able to do the report if the data I was dealing with didn't contain thousands of characters per cell. The way I can see myself getting round this is by assigning a Unique Reference number to each string before pulling the data into SAS.

What I haven't worked out, is how to apply the same Reference Number to a string of text that appears in multiple observations. I'll try give an example below, though this is the first time using this site (as someone asking a question) so please excuse the terrible data example.

**Not the results I want**

AccountID     Comments      Unique_Ref

A1111111      Sample1       00000001

A2222222      Sample2       00000002

A3333333      Sample1       00000003

A4444444      Sample3       00000004

**Results I do want**

AccountID     Comments      Unique_Ref

A1111111      Sample1       00000001

A2222222      Sample2       00000002

A3333333      Sample1       00000001

A4444444      Sample3       00000003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what DB you're using, you can do this with a window function.

```
SELECT 
  AccountID, 
  Comments, 
  RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Comments) AS Unique_Ref
FROM MyTable
```

This will assign each row with the same `Comments` value the same `Unique_Ref` value.

Comment: Needed a little editting, but you gave me the right idea. Just needed to add the Order By in the OVER statement. Much appreciated!

Comment: No prob bob :) .